# Laravel Request return array instead of value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-request

i have Laravel project, i created a post route on api.php, that just returning data that i send:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('client', fn(Request $req) => response()->json($req->key));
```

i send an object by axios `{ "key" : "test" }` so i expected the code above to return me just string `"test"` so can i use it with Model::where(). but it return me an object:

```json
{
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "dep": {
        "w": 0,
        "n": 0
    },
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": "test",
    "_value": "test"
}
```

i always use `$req->anykey` and its work but i don't know what's happen this time, any help pleas.

##### UPDATE 1

i tried `$req->input('key')` same response.

Comment: that response is a vuejs object, so if you are using vuejs that is normal. Check the network tab for the url you called and you will see only the `"test"` string present in the response.

Comment: yes i use vuejs, but i think problem not here,  cuz if i use ```Model::where('key', $req->key)``` return me all records

Comment: can you add the code to your question ? also a better way to check if the value is correct is to use `dd($req->key)` and check the network tab, not console.log()

Comment: did you send the `ref()` ? or `ref().value` ?

Comment: In Vue3 is ref,value

Comment: Thanks guys. It's my mistake, i was sending ```ref()```, i am new with ```script setup```